# Rebuild Solution - "Parameter not supported by the "SignFile" Task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create a small Excel-Addin with just 1 Project in the Solution.
I downloaded the Tools at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c144a87-917a-4eb1-8716-da61f7efdafc/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-march-2014-update-now-available?forum=lightswitch and could create a Add-In.

I can even debug it, but as soon as I rebuild the Solution, i get the 2 following errors:

> Error 1   The "TargetFrameworkVersion" parameter is not supported by the
>   "SignFile" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a
>   settable public instance property.
>   Error   2   The "SignFile" task could
>   not be initialized with its input parameters.

Funny enought, on another machine the rebuilding is working perfectly and as far as the other developer knows he didn't do anything special.

I checked a bout abut this SignFile Task, f.e. :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164304.aspx , but when I unload the Project and check the file, there are no such entries there.

On the problematic machine I created a new AddIn-Solution and run even on a empty Solution in the exact same problems.

P.S.: I can't uncheck the "Sign the ClickOnce manifists" Checkbox in the Signing tab. From what I've found a certifate expired, but how is that possible if I create a new Solution?

Thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: I have the same problem.
If you find a solution it would be very nice to provide the answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seem to be a bug with visual studio. I had the issue with Visual Studio Premium 2013 update 2. But with Update 3 (12.0.30723.00), the issue is gone.

Comment: Thank you Sir, can you tell me which version exactly you have?

Comment: That's weird. I get this error since I've updated to Update 3 (12.0.30723.00)

Comment: Try creating a new project, instead of re-opeing the old one.

Comment: This would mean there is a difference between the project files of VS2013 and VS2013.3? Do you know the difference? ToolsVersion possibly? Something else?

Comment: Updating from VS2013 ("Update 0") to VS2013 Update 4 solved my issue.

Comment: See the warning at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164304.aspx 

"Starting in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, this task has a new signature that allows you to specify the target framework version for the file."